# вместо страницы возвращается список файлов(Index of /)

Tags: php, apache, centos, httpd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю толли php не работает толи хз).
Хотя команда php -v
возвращает результат

```
[root@94 www]# php -v
```

PHP 7.2.20 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2019 13:01:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

мой сервер Centos 6: Apache+Ngix+php

вот мой nginx conf

```
server {



 listen 80;

 server_name  emrdeveloper.ru www.emrdeveloper.ru;

  #access_log  /var/log/nginx/vps_access.log;

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|doc|docx|pdf|xls|xlsx|rar|zip|tbz|7z|exe)$ {

  root /var/www/tracex/public/;

  expires 10d;

  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
     deny  all;
  }

  location = /stat {

  stub_status on;

  access_log  off;

#   allow xx.xx.xx.xx;

#   deny all;

                 }

location / {

proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;

proxy_redirect     off;

log_not_found     off;

proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;

proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```

}

и httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

  ServerName emrdeveloper.ru

  ServerAlias www.emrdeveloper.ru

   DocumentRoot /var/www/tracex/public

<Directory "/var/www/tracex/public">


  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

теперь не обрабатывает php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит потому что апач не знает как обрабатывать php  файлы.
в httpd.conf добавь:

```
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

а там /etc/httpd/conf.d должен быть файл (раз ты php установил) php.conf
 в котором написано что делать с php файлами

```
AddType text/html .php

<IfModule  mod_php7.c>
  <FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  </FilesMatch>

  #
  # Uncomment the following lines to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
  # files as PHP source code:
  #
  #<FilesMatch \.phps$>
  #    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
  #</FilesMatch>

  #
  # Apache specific PHP configuration options
  # those can be override in each configured vhost
  #
  php_value session.save_handler "files"
  php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
  php_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "/var/lib/php/wsdlcache"

  #php_value opcache.file_cache   "/var/lib/php/opcache"
</IfModule>
```

либо добавь это в  httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте сказать апачу что при запросе этой директории нужно вызывать определенные файлы и перезапустите апач

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

  ServerName emrdeveloper.ru

  ServerAlias www.emrdeveloper.ru

   DocumentRoot /var/www/tracex/public

<Directory "/var/www/tracex/public">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  Require all granted
  AllowOverride All
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Попробовал но выдает ошибку такую в логах
[Sat Jul 20 03:41:43 2019] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /

Comment: решилось эта ошибка когда я убрал  Require all granted в VirtualHost-e. Но теперь уже  возвращается просто текст файла index.php

Comment: php не работает походу. Так как страница не рендрица а просто возвращает текст

Comment: Видимо вам нужно включить его модуль для Апача через sudo a2enmod php7.2  и затем 
sudo service apache2 restart.

Comment: a2enmod не существует и apache2 тоже теперь же httpd